# .makeCopy - copy values only - script modification

Tags: google-sheets

could you please advise how to modify the script in google spreadsheets, to copy VALUES only ?

```
function Report() {
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var folderID = "1czYdbjaPOqUmpPbnB2Fl0LGX_eVYWskD"; 
  var LPSheetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var LPSheet = LPSheetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("RAW Master CHF");
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var fileName = "LP Report "  
  

  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(LPSheetSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName , folder)
  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("RAW Master CHF");
```

It works, but copy sheets with all formulas. Can we add some another argument/modify the script to copy/paste just values?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add function to `copy paste value` after you have create the new sheet, so that it will loop through all the sheets and replace all formula with value only:

```
function Report() {
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var folderID = "1QmdQ0meKRbxe2GIg9rRkcTWOcKVKHWvn"; 
  var LPSheetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var fileName = "LP Report "  
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(LPSheetSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy(fileName , folder));
  
  var destSheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < destSheets.length;i++){
    var sheet = destSheets[i];
    var copyRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
    copyRange.copyTo(copyRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but not working, still copying the formulas and not values :(

Comment: I have tested and it is working, did you change the `Folder ID` as it is using my version to run it, after create the copy of workbook, it will loop through all the sheet and replace all formula with value

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*Use [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange), [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) and [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).*

### Explanation

Once you have made a copy of the file, you can replace all its formulas with values combining the mentioned methods.

### Code

```
function formula2value() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var values = sheets[i].getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
    sheets[i].getDataRange().setValues(values)
  }
}
```

### References

- [Sheet: getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [Range: getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [Range: setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)